# Stop geofencing when app terminates

Tags: ios, gps, geofencing

I want to stop geofencing when a user terminates the app, because sometimes users really want to make the little geofence thingy in the corner go away. However, I can't use -applicationWillTerminate: because that method isn't consistently called, and the app isn't restarted anymore when a geofencing notification is sent. I'm just monitoring for someone to leave a 400 meter region (the region around a bar or event).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If the user has given permission for your app to use location in the background then they can control it from settings - terminating an app is not the right solution.  There is no 100% guaranteed method that executes when your app is terminated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use "requestAlwaysAuthorization" for location, geofence will stop working when the user terminates the app. This is only for iOS8

According to Apple Docs -

> The region monitoring service delivers events normally while an app is running in the foreground or background. (You can use this service for both geographic and beacon regions.) For a terminated iOS app, this service relaunches the app to deliver events. Use of this service requires “Always” authorization from the user".